# Functions as types in swift4

Tags: xcode, function, types, swift4

I am a beginner in Swift 4. I want the syntax for a function that has no parameters and returns nothing. For example, a function that has one double as a parameter and returns value of double is written as `(Double) -> Double`. Now how do I write it with no parameters and no return value just a simple function? Thanks.

Comment: `func someFunc() { ... }` or if you want to be more conscious about it (no, you don't _really_ need to be) then it is still a valid syntax `func someFunc() -> () { ... }`

Comment: On another note ___functions are just a special case of closures___. In **Swift** function types and closure types are unified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
    func funcName() {
      //func body
    }
```

you should read [the beginner guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1)